# Automate printing with options?

Tags: pdf, preview, printing, automation

I am trying to print a file (a pdf), without intervention. Not Automator specific, I can deal with applescript or terminal or whatever. The specifics of what I want are:

- Print to specific Printer
- Print to specific Page Size (Non-Standard)
- Auto-Rotated (Optional)
- Scale to Fit, Print Entire Page (Ends up being 109 to 112%. 110% works)

I can do this manually through Preview's print menu, only the page size is non-default, but I want to automate it, drag and drop, somehow.

**Things I tried:**

1. If I print from Finder, it uses Preview, but it's blown out of size, and wrong Page size.
2. If I drag it onto the printer in ~/Library/Printers/printername, it's like using LP, but without the options.
3. Applescript's printing options are poorly documented.
4. Automator's "Print Finder Items" it's like #1.
5. Automator's "Print Images" is like Preview but "Scale to Fit" does not work like Preview does, I can't choose the page size, and "Auto-Rotate" doesn't work at all.
6. **If I print from terminal via LP or LPR, I can set page size and orientation/fit-to-page, but I can't scale it to 110%. This is the closest thing to what I want.**

### How can I do this? It shouldn't be so hard, I want to do what the GUI can, not like I want extra features.

Worst case, how can I emulate mouse or keyboard control of Preview's print menu? All that would be needed is to 1. open file, 2. Bring up print menu, 3. switch to a preset or page size, as all the other options **including scaling are default**., 4. press print/enter.

Comment: For emulating mouse or keyboard control (and a slew of other features you'll wonder how you ever lived without) you might check out [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Let's split the problem into two parts: scaling and printing.

## Scaling

You can scale a PDF on the command line. Consider creating a temporary, scaled, PDF to print.

See [scaling PDF content and page dimensions from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/676013/scaling-pdf-content-and-page-dimensions-from-command-line) for suggested approaches to this. The highest voted answer suggests using [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) with a command like:

```
cpdf -scale-page "1.1 1.1" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

An alternative tool is [`sips`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html). This tool is included with OS X and is surprisingly capable.

## Printing

As you have discovered, OS X's printing system is the [Common Unix Printing System](http://www.cups.org) (CUPS). CUPS includes the command line tool `lpr` which can accept [all the settings and options](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html) you need.

For printing the PDF via the command line see:

- [Print PDF from Command Line – cups-pdf, lpr -P PDF](http://terokarvinen.com/2011/print-pdf-from-command-line-cups-pdf-lpr-p-pdf)
- [CUPS printing of pdf files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27596/cups-printing-of-pdf-files)

To list the available printers, use:

```
lpstat -p -d
```

To print a PDF file to the default printer, use:

```
lpr file.pdf
```

Comment: might it be possible to use a `pipe` and do the whole shebang at once? like: `cpdf -scale-page "1.1 1.1" in.pdf |  lpr ` ?

Comment: With `cpdf` that might be possible. With `sips` it would have to go via a file. I suspect a short bash script or even an AppleScript droplet would wrap the command up well.

Comment: Considering CPDF can do cropping and scaling in a single command then piping to LP, this should be the best for me. I'll need to test it out.

Comment: You can install [RWTS PDFwriter](https://github.com/rodyager/RWTS-PDFwriter) with `brew install rwts-pdfwriter` (requires macOS Big Sur, to install on macOS Catalina install [Version 1.01](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/7d7e9da0c2dccfc547e626cae12d0d26f4a9f70a/Casks/rwts-pdfwriter.rb)).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was using `open` and `osascript` along with [a tool `pdfcrop` from MacRumor's forum user **Oligarch**](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/pdf-command-line-tools.1354754/) (Wayback Machine backup to [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150619012643/http://users.skynet.be/tools/PDFTools.tgz))

```
./pdfcrop /path/to/file.pdf -u in -p 6.68 1.82 -a tr -o 0.14 0.23 > ./0.pdf && \
./pdfcrop /path/to/file.pdf -b m -u in -p 3.30 1.82 -a tr -o 0.14 0.23 > ./1.pdf && \
./pdfcrop /path/to/file.pdf -b m -u in -p 3.38 1.78 -a tr -o 3.43 0.24 > ./2.pdf && \
open ./1.pdf ./2.pdf && \
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to delete POSIX file "'/path/to/file.pdf'"' -e 'tell application "Finder" to delete POSIX file "'./1.pdf'"' -e 'tell application "Finder" to delete POSIX file "'./2.pdf'"'
```

1. It takes the original file, and creates three copies. One with the pdf cropped to size (crop box, none destructive) that I keep, and two cropped to size (media box) that are temporary.
2. It then opens them with Preview, as two pages/files in the same window.
3. It then tells Finder via Applescript to **delete** the temporary files, in a Finder, move to the trash manner. Same as if I `⌘-Delete` the files.
4. Once in Preview, I can `⌘-P` to print both files. Only thing I need to do is change the paper size, Preview handles the scaling.

Obviously, it doesn't do everything I want, but it helps reducing the amount of manual cropping and going back and forth to make sure everything I need printed is printed.

**Since CPDF can scale and crop, It should be easier to do all via command line. I just need to test it out.**